# What does increase the margins when the form appears?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you click the second orange button at this [page](https://antilopagold.su/religioznaya-tematika/podveski-i-medalony/bronzovaya-natelnaya-ikonka-svyataya-troitsa-na-shnurke-detail) white form will appear and something will increase the margins for the div.container. How to find out what or who is it doing?

Comment: Please provide the necessary code. It's easier then trying to debug the whole page.

Comment: No idea what margins you are talking about here. The script for this modal disables the main scrollbar of the page, so that naturally makes the content “jump” a bit sideways.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 1):

body is set to overflow:hidden  =  scrollbar dissapears so the content moves :)

Comment: Thank you. And what the best sites doing with this shift to neutralize it?

Comment: to neutralize this shift I added such js-code: jQuery("body").css("padding-right","17px"); jQuery("nav > .container").css("padding-left","6px");